# Arduino + WiFi 101 Gerber Files

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, hardware, pcb-design

Is it possible to get the Gerber files for the Arduino Uno r3 and the WiFi 101?  I've been teaching myself the SW side of this hobby (with much help from SE Arduino) and I'd like to better understand, or at least get some exposure to, the HW side.

Are the Arduino Uno and WiFi 101 Gerber files available to the general public or are they considered IP?  I am under the impression that it is open source but I'm not sure where the OS boundary ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [Arduino UNO](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and [Wifi shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield101) websites in the Documentation section you can download the Schematic (PDF) and PCB layout (Eagle) files. The page already says

> The Uno is open-source hardware! You can build your own board using
>   the follwing files

With the free version of [Eagle](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/freeware/), you can open it and export to gerber file format.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me.  I'll take a look.  I did see Eagle files I just didn't know what they were.